# BuddyPress - Search members by name and also by username

Tags: search

Im trying to find a way to set the members search by name and also by username.

Now it seems to search only by name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Somebody on the BuddyPress support forums](http://buddypress.org/community/groups/creating-extending/forum/topic/search-members-by-username/) had this to say:

> I don’t recommend to change the core files of buddypress. The best way
>   to do it is to write a custom code (I don’t know how to guide you). So
>   if you don’t mind changing the core files, here is a quick way.
>
> Open `/buddypress/bp-core/bp-core-classes.php` and change the
>
> ```
> $sql['where_searchterms'] = “AND pd.value LIKE ‘%%$search_terms%%’”;
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> $sql['where_searchterms'] = “AND (pd.value LIKE ‘%%$search_terms%%’ OR 
>     u.user_login LIKE’%%$search_terms%%’)” ;
> ```
>
> If someone can guide us how to do it in `bp-custom.php`, it would be
>   great.

Comment: Can somebody help us with a functions.php or bp-custom.php code to implement the above change? Thanks